# How can I get the canvas of map object?

Tags: openlayers, angular

I have an angular component in my application.

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  isActive: boolean = false;

  constructor(private mapComponent: MapComponent) {

  }

  do(){
    console.log(this.mapComponent.map?.getOverlayContainer())
    console.log(this.mapComponent.map?.getView())
    console.log(this.mapComponent.map?.getViewport())
  }
}
```

I want to get canvas object of the map component. Bu I could not find in map object.
How can I get map canvas?

Comment: In OpenLayers 6 there can be multiple canvases - you can access them using querySelectorAll as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/export-map.html - `map.getTargetElement().querySelectorAll` would be more specific than `document.querySelectorAll`  OpenLayers 5 used a single canvas which could be accessed via render events https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/examples/export-map.html

Comment: Mike took the word right out of my mouth, with examples instead of my ramblings. I offhand don't know of a API that exposes the canvas directly and Mike's examples reinforce my doubt.  You know the container, the canvas has to be a child of that container, use selectors to find it. Look at the first example, line 36, and let us know if that helps solve your issue.

Comment: I am getting the first canvas of `var item = this.mapComponent.map?.getTargetElement().querySelectorAll('.ol-layer canvas')` and `window.open(item.toDataURL("image/png"))` but window does not show this image. The error is "Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL"

Comment: There are some workarounds for that error given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45493234/jspdf-not-allowed-to-navigate-top-frame-to-data-url